# how to delete duplicate dictionaries in list of dictionaries and extract the values of dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, duplicate

delete duplicate dictionaries in list of dictionary and extract the values of dictionary

```
id=842
mg=[ 
       {"ss": 81,  "rr": 842, "cd": 81},
            {"ss": 842, "rr": 81,  "cd": 81},
            {"ss": 81,  "rr": 842, "cd": 81},
            {"ss": 842,  "rr": 81, "cd": 81},
            {"ss": 82,  "rr": 842, "cd": 82},
             {"ss": 82,  "rr": 842, "cd": 82},
            {"ss": 83,  "rr": 842, "cd": 83},
            {"ss": 842,  "rr": 83, "cd": 83},
    ]
new_d = []
for x in mg:
    if x not in new_d:
        new_d.append(x) 
mg=new_d

mglist=[]   
length=len(mg)      
for i in range(length):
    if mg[i].rr==id:
        if mg[i] not in mglist:
            cr+=1
            mglist.append(mg[i])
    if mg[i].ss==id:
        if mg[i] not in mglist:
            cs+=1
            mglist.append(mg[i])
print(cr)
print(cs)
```

I want to delete duplicate rows and then count frequency of id (in first and second column) in this list of dictionary
how I could solve my problem with iteration and remove duplication
how to delete duplicate dictionaries in list of dictionaries and extract the values of dictionary?

Comment: This is not about data science, you could ask on https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
#remove duplicates
new_d = [i for n, i in enumerate(mg) if i not in mg[n + 1:]]

#check the data
cs_d = [i for n, i in enumerate(new_d) if i['ss'] == id]
cr_d = [i for n, i in enumerate(new_d) if i['rr'] == id]

#sample return
print(cs_d) #print dictionarys, where ss=id
print(len(cs_d)) #print number of elements, where ss=id
```

Or everything inside a single loop to increase performance:

```
cs_d = []
cr_d = []
for n, i in enumerate(mg):
    #check, if dict is unique
    if i not in mg[n + 1:]:
        #store cs
        if i['ss'] == id:
            cs_d.append(i)

        #store cr
        if i['rr'] == id:
            cr_d.append(i)
```

Alternatively, you could use a `pandas.Dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(mg)

#get unique mg list
df_unique = df.drop_duplicates()

#count cs, where ss==id
cs = df_unique.ss.value_counts()[id]

#count cr, where rr==id
cr = df_unique.rr.value_counts()[id]

#extract values, where ss==id
print( df_unique.loc[df_unique.ss == id] )
#    ss  rr  cd
#1  842  81  81
#7  842  83  83

#extract values, where rr==id
print( df_unique.loc[df_unique.rr == id] )
#   ss   rr  cd
#0  81  842  81
#4  82  842  82
#6  83  842  83
```

Comment: thanks but how we can solve it, if we would like to do it without using Pandas?

Comment: I updated the post accordingly